# Azure File Share and soft link

Tags: azure, iis, azure-storage, symlink, azure-files

My idea is to have a folder under the IIS Website such that when a file is loaded onto that folder through the website it will automatically copy over to a second website in a different server.

So to perform this I have the idea of putting a soft link from the folder in Azure File Share to both the sites such that there is one file location shared between the sites.

The issue I am facing is after creation of the soft link, although the folder structure is visible on the IIS website, the website itself is unable to identify the folders and throws location not found error when upload attempt is performed.

Is there a way to setup soft link from AFS to IIS folders.

Comment: Would you please share us with your detailed code for further research?

Comment: The code is a third party application code that points to a file inside the folder structure of the application to store files so cannot provide the code. I am trying to replace the folder with a symlink with azure file share as the source and folder as the target